# nullpointer exception when querying database

Tags: java, database, hibernate, session

I am trying to query from the database its a hibernate project

```
public class FeedInputParamsDaoImpl implements IFeedInputParamsDao {
 @Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}

private int BATCH_SIZE = 50;

public Session getSession() {
/*null pointer exception*/Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    return session;
}
      @Override
public List<FeedInputParams> getAllFeedInputParamslist (int feedKey) {
    String queryString = "from FeedInputParams as feedInputParams where feedInputParams.feedKey > ?";
    Session session =  getSession();
    Query query = session.createQuery(queryString);
    query.setParameter(0, feedKey);
    List<FeedInputParams> feedInputParamsList = query.list();
    return feedInputParamsList;
}

}
```

And this **getAllFeedInputParamslist (int feedKey)** is called from the method

```
  public void readFile()
        throws Exception {  
    FeedInputParamsDaoImpl feedInputParamsDaoImpl=new FeedInputParamsDaoImpl();
    List<FeedInputParams> feedInputParamsList=feedInputParamsDaoImpl.getAllFeedInputParamslist(0);
    System.out.println("feedInputParamsList...."+feedInputParamsList);

}
```

I am getting **null pointer exception**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at com.vxl.appanalytix.dao.impl.FeedInputParamsDaoImpl.getSession(FeedInputParamsDaoImpl.java:28) 
 at com.vxl.appanalytix.dao.impl.FeedInputParamsDaoImpl.getAllFeedInputParamslist(FeedInputParamsD0Impl.java:44) 
at
```

Comment: show us the stacktrace

Comment: Your `sessionFactory` is `NULL`, which means it was not `Autowired` properly!

Comment: @midhunjose Autowired means that spring is suppose to look in it's xml files for an instance of SessionFactory - it did not find such a thing, thus you get a null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SessionFactory is null - it was not autowired by spring for some reason. Do you have any annotation on the FeedInputParamsDaoImpl class?